# Sylius shop - how to render product image in popup cart in header?

Tags: sylius

in template themes/xxx/templates/bundles/SyliusShopBundle/Cart/Widget/_popup.html.twig
are rendered items in shopping cart.
There are variables item.product, item.quantity

Is there some way how to render product image, something like item.image?

I dumped variable {{dump(item.product)}}
and see images collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to retrieve from the product one image you want to display you can do it e.g. by `image.type` in twig to filter the image by type you can use `product.imagesByType('type')` then you can use `imagine_filter` to retrieve the image path in appropriate resolutions e.g. `product.imagesByType('thumbnail').first.path|imagine_filter(filter|default('sylius_shop_product_tiny_thumbnail'))`.

You can find all image types defined in sylius in https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/images/images.html

An example how to do it you will find in sylius code, for example here -> https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/f0ea6668bde5163d7e5a5b0f1ae28301ce6a9b14/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/views/Product/_mainImage.html.twig

```
{% if product.imagesByType('thumbnail') is not empty %}
    {% set path = product.imagesByType('thumbnail').first.path|imagine_filter(filter|default('sylius_shop_product_thumbnail')) %}
{% elseif product.images.first %}
    {% set path = product.images.first.path|imagine_filter(filter|default('sylius_shop_product_thumbnail')) %}
{% else %}
    {% set path = asset('assets/shop/img/200x200.png') %}
{% endif %}

<img src="{{ path }}" {{ sylius_test_html_attribute('main-image') }} alt="{{ product.name }}" class="ui bordered image" />
```